# what are difference between a bug and script issue?

Tags: testing

what are difference between a bug and script issue?

and when ever a testcase is failed, how to solve that testcase, i mean what are basic
points to check how the testcase is failed.

Answer (score 0):

The term "test case" is to generic - what do you mean by it in your context?

However generally in the test case you should identify the condition(s) that will make this test "passed". So if condition(s) is not satisfied the test is failed.

Generally the issue is some problem with something (for example, problem with the script). It may be the system configuration issue that prevents the script from successful execution or it may be an error in the script code, and this will be a bug in the script.